# Push a NuGet package to VSTS with .NET CLI

Tags: nuget, dotnet-cli, azure-artifacts

I'm trying to publish a NuGet package to a private VSTS feed. I'd like to achieve that using **only** .NET CLI and without creating or modifying a nuget.config file.

I've tried to do:

```
dotnet nuget push <PackageName> --source https://XXX.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/YYY/nuget/v3/index.json --api-key <VSTS UserName>:<PersonalAccessToken>
```

I get:

```
error: Unable to load the service index for source https://XXX.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/YYY/nuget/v3/index.json.
error: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
```

I can see in Fiddler that .NET CLI sends only a GET request to `https://XXX.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/YYY/nuget/v3/index.json` without any authorization token. That request ends with 401.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The NuGet package credential and API key should be added in the `NuGet.config` file.

So before using the `dotnet nuget push` command, you should add the credential and API key in `NuGet.config` as below two commands:

```
nuget sources Add -Name "mysource" -Source "https://XXX.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/YYY/nuget/v3/index.json" -username name -password PAT
nuget setapikey mykey -source mysource
```

Then push the NuGet package through the `dotnet nuget push` command:

```
dotnet nuget push packagename.nupkg --source mysource --api-key mykey
```

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for an option that: 
a) doesn't require to store the keys in NuGet config as I wanted to check in the file to repository
b) doesn't require nuget.exe
But I guess, it can't be done (yet?)

Comment: Yeah, it can not be done. The credentials should be searched in nuget.config file as the description https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-nuget-push says: "The `dotnet nuget push` command pushes a package to the server and publishes it. The push command uses server and credential details found in the system's NuGet config file or chain of config files. "

Comment: Note that you won't need either the setapikey line or the --api-key parameter when pushing to VSTS Package Management. Otherwise though, the answer is correct.

You can manually construct a NuGet.config without using nuget.exe, if you'd like. There's a reference here that can help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/nuget-config-file#package-source-sections

Comment: You have used `mykey` and `PAT`. I suppose they do not represent the same value. How then can I generate this `mykey`?

Comment: @Andre Soares: Yes, mykey and PAT do not represent the same value: "The NuGet client's push command requires an API key. [With VSTS Package Server] You can use any non-empty string you want". Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/package/nuget/publish?view=vsts

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT is `nuget setapikey mykey` needed? when you use `--api-key mykey`

Comment: "Saves an API key for a given server URL into NuGet.Config so that it doesn't need to be entered for subsequent commands."

Comment: It would mean that I don't need to use `--api-key mykey` then

Comment: oh nevermind I didn't read all comments, it was answered by Alex

Comment: I'm convinced none of microsofts shitty vsts tasks work for nuget. Every avenue we try there are issues.

Comment: In my case had to push a package to GitHub Package Registry so did: `nuget setapikey <github-token-with-repo-permissions> -source github`. It added some gibberish to `%appdata%\NuGet\NuGet.Config` and then could push the package.